# How to run functions after css animation ends

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I use vue3.
I made it bigger when I put the mouse on the box.

```
.curl:hover {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

I would like to inform user that the animation is over after the size has grown.

In other words, Like animate() in jquery, I want to run function() indicating that the animation is finished. after the animation ends.

Does css or vue have this feature without jquery?

Comment: Hi, You can use setTimeout to delay the function execution for the time animation runs.

Comment: Note that your code doesn't show anything related to CSS animations. You're just showing a hover pseudoclass, not even with a `transition` rule if you mistakenly call transitions "animation"... So, it sounds like you're looking for either the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) or [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) event, but your question _absolutely_ needs [more details to be a proper question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) to answer your query below.

Basically, you need to specify a type of JavaScript handler, `animationend`, using an `eventhandler` add function, passing the method you wish to run in as the second argument, and setting the element you are animating as the element to add the event to.

**I have commented in the code the parts that are relevant**

```js
//Set a reference to the animated element
const animated = document.getElementById("divBoii");

//Add animation event listener, with attached function.
animated.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  console.log('Animation ended');
  document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML=":)";
});
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
  /*Animation that is assigned to animated div */
  @keyframes animation{
    0%{
      padding:5%;
      height:auto;
    }
    100%{
      padding:10%;
      height:auto;
    }
  }
  body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:teal;
  }
  #divBoii{
    margin:40%;
    margin-top:10%;
    width:10%;
    padding:5%;
    background-color:green;
  }
  /*Assign animation to div*/
  #divBoii:hover {
    animation-name:animation;
    animation-duration:3s;
  }
  
  </style>
  <body><div id="alert">
        This will be a smiley face when animation ends
      </div>
      <div id="divBoii">
      Here is some content we are going to animate
      </div>
  
  </body>
</head>
```